# How do I stop the browser from scrolling to the top when an "#section" link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following link:

```
<a href="#section">Section</a>
```

Now I really want this link to be working so the url will be changed to

```
mypage.html#section
```

But than on the other hand, if I just keep the code as it is, the browser would scroll the page back to the top automatically, and I don't want that to happen.

Obviously `return false;` will not suffice because it will not change the url.

Any ideas?

(Thanks)

Comment: You wan't to change the URL in order to?

Comment: In order to have a url that reflects the state in which the website is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to click an anchor that ties to a hash. Which is going to attempt to jump to the the appropriate element with that name. If it does not find that name it will just end up at the top. This is normal behavior.

It seems like you want to change that, from which I recommend not using and anchor and adding the `#section` hash via JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.location.hash = '#section'; return false;">Section</a>
```

That should give you your desired result.